# Window scroll effect like Shazam

Tags: react-native, swipe-gesture, shazam

I need to create an effect of opening and closing a component where the opening/closing follows the swipe of the finger, exactly as it works in Shazan. I confess that I do not know the name that would be given to this effect.

I got a similar result with react-native-swipe-gestures, but I need something smoother.

Below I leave a gif with the result I need to achieve

[image]